# Trying to load images in my slot machine iPhone app but getting an error (NSInvalidArgumentException)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I'm new to the hole Xcode/objective-c thing so it would be kind answering my questions in a way I can understand you :) 
My problem is: I'm trying to create a slot machine with a picker and a button (to spin the wheels of course ;) ) so I'm implementing 5 images (apple,crown,cherry,lemon,seven,banana) but at the point when I start the app I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage initWithImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b649b0'

My code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIImage *apple = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];
UIImage *banana = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banana.png"];    
UIImage *cherry = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cherry.png"];
UIImage *crown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crown.png"];
UIImage *lemon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lemon.png"];
UIImage *seven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seven.png"];    

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    UIImageView *appleView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:apple];
    UIImageView *bananaView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:banana];    
    UIImageView *cherryView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:cherry];    
    UIImageView *crownView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:crown];   
    UIImageView *lemonView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:lemon];   
    UIImageView *sevenView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:seven];    

    NSArray *imageViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:appleView, bananaView, cherryView, crownView, lemonView, sevenView, nil];

    NSString *fieldName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d", i];
    [self setValue: imageViewArray forKey:fieldName];
    [fieldName release];
    [imageViewArray release];
    [appleView release];
    [bananaView release];
    [cherryView release];
    [crownView release];
    [lemonView release];
    [sevenView release];
```

I've been looking around for typos quite some time but didn't find any. It would be really nice if someone could give me a hint. If the supported code isn't enough, feel free to ask for more.(Just copied the section where the error occurred) Sorry for my bad english but it's not my native language :)

/edit: I should've said, that the original error had been: SIGABRT, but it looks like this error seems to mean a lot without any context :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your image views with

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: ...]
```

NOT

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithImage: ...]
```